# Compression of a single RGB image ( with c++ )

Tags: c++, image, opengl, ffmpeg, compression

I am currently streaming my OpenGL rendered images through a websocket. I use the ZLib compression to compress the RGB data on the server side. On the client side I simply decompress and show the images.

My compression steps :

1. [S3TC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression) Texture compression from OpenGL
2. ZLib compression of step 1 with Qt framework

How can I compress even further? Is MPEG-4 encoding of a simple image an option or even possible? **How can I reduce the image size even further?**

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?hl=en i read this sometime ago, not sure about its usage though

Comment: How about using JPeg for single image compression?

Comment: You can use e.g. libav to create a *movie*

Answer (score 0):

S3TC is lossy, so if you want more compression, use another lossy approach, like JPEG, and crank up the compression until you don't like the result.  Then back off.

Answer (score 0):

If images are similar to each other, use some standard one-pass video compression algorithm. If images are distinct, why wouldn't you just use JPEG or some other (more modern) image compression algorithm? In either case it should be quite easy to find suitable libraries for server and client side, no need to invent and develop your own codecs and formats.